# How do you reverse a wav file?

Tags: wav

I want to reverse a wav file. I am not sure how to do this however. I have read that you need to reverse the sample stream instead of the byte stream, but I am not sure what people mean by this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You begin by reading up on WAV file specifications so you understand at least the basics. Then you go look to see if there are libraries available for manipulating WAV files. Then you write some code to do what you want. When you hit a point in your code where you're stuck, you come here, show us your code, and ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to get some kind of soud manipulation going is to use the Python language  + Pygame -

Pygame allows you to read the contents of a .wav file into a value array with 5 or 6 lines of program - in total. The Python language allow you to revese that with a simple expression, and you will need more 2 or 3 function calls to pygame to either save the wav file or play it back.

You cna get the latest Python at http://www.python.org , and them look for instructions on how to install modules with `pip` - at which point you woill be able to install pygame. Then, learn some Python basics if you don't already know, and follow Pygame's documentations at:

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sndarray.html

Answer (score 0):

That's right, you need to reverse the samples and not the bytes.
Here's a brief summary from this [tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/reversing-a-wav-file-in-c-482fc3dfe3c4).
Grab the bytes after the metadata (usually at index 44).
Reverse the samples by using a for loop:

```
private static byte[] ReverseTheForwardsArrayWithOnlyAudioData(int bytesPerSample, byte[] forwardsArrayWithOnlyAudioData)
{
    int length = forwardsArrayWithOnlyAudioData.Length;
    byte[] reversedArrayWithOnlyAudioData = new byte[length];
    int sampleIdentifier = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (i != 0 && i % bytesPerSample == 0)
        {
            sampleIdentifier += 2 * bytesPerSample;
        }
        int index = length - bytesPerSample - sampleIdentifier + i;
        reversedArrayWithOnlyAudioData[i] = forwardsArrayWithOnlyAudioData[index];
    }
    return reversedArrayWithOnlyAudioData;
}
```